# D3.js gaps in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, d3.js

The google map I am using appears to be split by vertical bars. These bars split different parts of the map as one zooms. What could be causing this?

The attached image displays the effect of the split on the street names.

[image: Google map]

Comment: Are you using Chrome version34 ?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be browser related. I mainly use Firefox but it appears the same way on Chrome 34